# Duplicate records into same table with variation PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Have been looking for examples of this but apparently I don't know the terminology well enough to find the answer:

Utilizing PHP / MySql, I'm trying to duplicate records in a table while editing portions of that data.

Have an existing table 'information' that looks like this:

```
1 ID - Int11 AutoIncrement

2 elementID - Int11 Unique

3 text - text utf8

4 loopID - Int11

5 created - datetime

6 modified - datetime
```

Both the 'elementID' and 'loopID' fields contain values in which the LAST FOUR DIGITS represent an embedded identifier, in this case a 'page' in the system.  So for example:

Page '9000' elementID's recorded as

```
100019000
100029000
100039000
```

and Page '9000' loopID's recorded as

```
1009000
1019000
1029000
```

Page '9001' elementID's records are recorded as

```
100019001
100029001
100039001
```

and Page '9001' loopID's records are recorded as

```
1009001
1019001
1029001
```

Hopefully you get the idea.

What I want to do is when a new page is created (say in this case 9002), the end user can choose to duplicate all record data from a previous page (say in this case they want to duplicate 9001).

Before I dive into this, I really need to understand what the best method would be.

At first I was thinking I would want to query all records matching 9001 into an array, replace all of the last-4 digit 9001's in elementID and loop with 9002's, replace the 'created' and 'modified' dates to today, and then write the resulting array back into the database as new entries?  If so, at what point should the replacement occur, during the query, or during the write back to the database?

Then as I have started thinking further it is leading me to wonder if this should be done in a manner similar to this instead:

```
INSERT INTO information...
SELECT REPLACE... 
FROM information
[WHERE ..]
```

I can see there are enough elements involved in this that generating it won't be easy for a database amateur such as I... If someone could point me to a proper example of this process it would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
declare newId int;
declare copyFromId int;
declare diff int;

set newId := 9002;
set copyFromId := 9001;
setdiff := newId - copyFromId; -- in this case it will be 1

select into your_table 
  select null,
         elementID + diff, -- so for 100019000 it will be 100019001
         text,
         loopID + diff, -- same as above
         now(),
         now()         
    from your_table
   where elementID mod 10000 = copyFromId; -- all lines with en elementId ending in copyFromId
```

Comment: Hi, thanks much! Toby is probably right given my experience (or lack thereof) - but this looks too cool to not try...  I follow the thinking here, though you are much smarter than I my friend ;-) not sure I understand the 'where elementID mod 10000' part - I thought mod was for returning a divisional remainder? so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how that will output... I would have been thinking something more like substr($input, -4)...?  Anyway I will certainly give this a try and report back tx again!

Comment: Divisional remainder is exactly what you want. Take a look at these examples http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c960a/39 When the divider is a an even 10, 100, 1000 and so on it will just cut of the part above, similar to substring, but for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first idea is the one to go with.

Pull out of the database all the records you want to copy and then execute queries on the db to add these back in after you have made the changes to the data.  Unless you need to do 10,000 queries this will be very fast.

Doing this in a SQL statement itself will be very complex and not necessary.  It is probably possible as a stored procedure but the best place to have it is in your `php`.